# How to fire off a workflow by clicking a link on a page...?

Tags: list, workflow

Just wondering what the best way to solve this would be...if it is possible...

I am wanting to put a some links onto a page that each represents a workflow for the list beneath it.  When the user selects an item in the list and clicks one of the links I want the workflow to start.

If there's nothing selected in the list, I want nothing to happen...or perhaps an error message.

Is this possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

- [4 Clicks or 1? Using jQuery to Start a SharePoint Workflow](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/04/21/4-clicks-or-1-using-jquery-to-start-a-sharepoint-workflow/)
- [Initiate a SharePoint workflow from a button on the list view](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/charleslee/archive/2009/11/24/77727.aspx)